# NServiceBus with Sql Server Transport Error

Tags: sql-server, nservicebus

I have configured NServiceBus to use Sql Server.

```
    Configure.With()
        .AutofacBuilder(container)
        .UseTransport<SqlServer>("aureus")
        .InMemorySubscriptionStorage()
        .UnicastBus()
        .DisableTimeoutManager()
        .CreateBus()
        .Start();
```

When I send a message in the controller.

```
this._bus.Send(new BillClient { Value = "testing." });
```

I get the error.
Failed to send message to address: [queue]
Invalid object name 'queue'.

My configuration is as follows:

```
  <UnicastBusConfig>
    <MessageEndpointMappings>
      <add Assembly="Aureus.Messages" Namespace="Aureus.Messages" Endpoint="queue"/>
    </MessageEndpointMappings>
  </UnicastBusConfig>
```

What have I missed? I can't find out if I need to run scripts / or initialise the queues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
.Start()
```

You need

```
.Start(() => Configure.Instance.ForInstallationOn<Windows>().Install());
```

To kick off the initialization of the queues.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert but I had to use the ConnectionString definition as the argument to .UseTransport() as shown below. In your post it's not clear what "aureus" will mean to NServiceBus software.

```
.UseTransport<SqlServer>(ConnectionString())


string ConnectionString()
{
    return "NServiceBus/Transport\" connectionString=\"Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial    Catalog=nservicebus;Integrated Security=True";
}
```

I was not able to use the ConnectionString name from my config file as an argument either. Here's the section of my config file fyi:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <!-- Message Bus ********************************************** -->
<add name="NServiceBus/Transport" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=nservicebus;Integrated Security=True" />
  <!-- Message Bus ********************************************** -->
</connectionStrings>
```

Also, for Endpoint in my config file, I had to use the namespace of my NServiceBus message handler class. Here's the endpoint section of my config file:

```
<UnicastBusConfig ForwardReceivedMessagesTo="audit">
    <MessageEndpointMappings>
    <!--Note - Endpoint must specify the Namespace of the server-->
    <add Assembly="My.Messages.Assemblyname" Namespace="My.Messages.AssemblyNamespace" Endpoint="MyMessageHandlerAssy.Namespace" />
    </MessageEndpointMappings>
</UnicastBusConfig>
```

Hope that helps you a bit.